# What are some useful strategies for understanding undocumented assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86

What are some useful strategies for tackling a list of undocumented assembly language instructions? Even as someone who writes assembly code, I find it to be challenging at times to understand someone *else's* code because the nature of assembly language means mentally having to keep track of CPU state at various points during the program. I've seen some success with getting a notepad and a pen and working through the program by hand. What are some other strategies? Let's take for example this function:

```
 ; cmp     edx,10
       ; jae     internal_error
    push    ebx ecx
    push    eax
    mov    ebx,eax
    mov    ecx,edx
    shld    edx,eax,2
    sub    ebx,edx
    sbb    ecx,0
    mov    eax,ebx
    mov    ebx,1999999Ah
    mul    ebx
    mov    eax,ecx
    imul    eax,ebx
    add    eax,edx
    pop    edx
    imul    ecx,eax,10
    sub    edx,ecx
    cmp    edx,10
    jb    somewhere
    sub    edx,10
    inc    eax
    pop    ecx ebx
    retn
```

Due to the nature of assembly language, it is not immediately apparent "what this code actually does" at a high level. To me, the process of understanding this is true "reverse engineering" but it doesn't necessarily need to apply to reading from a disassembler, it could just be someone else's assembler source code as well. In fact, sometimes without the help of IDA Pro or Binary Ninja disassembling a binary written in a HLL, reverse engineering assembly written in aassembly is more difficult.

Comment: push ebx ecx ?? is that typo

Comment: @blabb no this is not a disassembled program, it's a flat assembler program.

Answer (score 2):

My strategy is:

- not to be ashamed to use decompilers
- don't spend time on understanding each instruction. Analyzing which result the code gives with various input data is a much faster way to understand, what the function does as a whole.
- google for "magic constant 0x1999999A" and look at the fourth result
- enable autocomments in IDA

p.s. if you need to write down what each instruction does, you're either don't have the proper tools, or doing reversing wrong.